# What is the difference between myoblasts, myotubes and myocytes

Tags: muscles

I am struggling to grasp the difference between myoblasts, myotubes and myocytes.
If I am right, myoblasts are mononucleated and differentiate into myotubes which are muscle fibers.

Are myocytes the mature muscle cell? I can't find a good definition for this.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please share what prior research you've done here?

Answer (score 1):

On request I'm providing helpful explanation of the picture i have added for those who are new in learning

Myoblasts - focus on 'blast' which means related to early stage of cell which has not yet differentiated such cells are also called stem cells, once differentiated their fate is decided very much what they are going to be.

Myocyte - [cyte:cell] they are already differentiated, hence are fully specific about themselves what constituent they are going to become.

Myotubes - myocytes condense as a mass, also besides that they undergo elongation as well, which ultimately results into formation of bundle like structure. Now at this stage idea of a singular cell is lost, we can't pick up a part of it and say this is one cell.

May myotubes coalese and form few myofibril (imagine 1000 myotubes make 100 myofibril)
And bundle of 100 myofibril makes one myofibre/muscle fibre which has sneath covering called sarcolemma. Many such muscle fibres together (with the help of endomysium as connective tissue/glue) make muscle fascia which in turn with the help of perimysium(connective tissue/glue) and covering called epimysium makes up Muscle.

[image: This is answer]

Source:

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/347023906_Effects_of_External_Stimulators_on_Engineered_Skeletal_Muscle_Tissue_Maturation

Mueller, Claudia & Trujillo Miranda, Mairon & Maier, Michael & Heath, Daniel & O'Connor, Andrea & Salehi-Müller, Sahar. (2020). Effects of External Stimulators on Engineered Skeletal Muscle Tissue Maturation. Advanced Materials Interfaces. 8. 2001167. 10.1002/admi.202001167.